# How could I install Hortonworks' HDP?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, configuration, virtual

I am new on this and I want to know how could I install the solution provided by Hortonworks, HDP, (http://hortonworks.com/products/data-center/hdp/) following the next specification: I have 2 Virtual Machines and another local machine to work with, and I want to use the 2 VM as Master node and Worker node by the time I configure Apache SPARK.

But my question is: what do I have to do to install HDP correctly? I have to install te solution in my local machine and configure Apache SPARK to use those 2 Virtual Machines as Master node and Worker node? Or I must to install HDP in the 3 machines that I have?

I repeat that I am new on this, and it wold be very helpfull for me any answer or comment that you could give.

Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you are trying to deploy HDP on a cluster (MultiNode Enviroment)
>   use Apache Ambari to Install HDP and other services such as spark.

I have tried it on centos environment below are the steps and links for installation.

1. get the repo by using the command below

> wget 
>   http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.2.2.0/ambari.repo

2. Install Ambari by using the command below

> yum install ambari-server

3. Start the server by using the command below

> ambari-server start

4. Now you can setup your by going to web browser and typing

> http://:8080.

Now you can select the desired HDP version. Add the other nodes and services and deploy your cluster.

[Detailed steps for installation can be found here](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.1/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap3.html)